# gsutil doesn't work: "AttributeError: 'SymbolDatabase' object has no attribute 'RegisterServiceDescriptor'"

Tags: gsutil

The gsutil command in my VM is failing with the following error:
   (...)
    packages/google/iam/v1/iam_policy_pb2.py", line 296, in 
    _sym_db.RegisterServiceDescriptor(_IAMPOLICY)

```
AttributeError: 'SymbolDatabase' object has no attribute 'RegisterServiceDescriptor'
```

Ideas??

Comment: Could tell us which examples are you using so that we can reproduce the problem and troubleshoot?   What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: I see this error when trying to run "gsutil help", for example. Or even just "gsutil". As my data was stuck on my VM, I wrote a python script to copy it to cloud storage. So, although the error happens on the iam_policy proto file, apparently it's not related to IAM permissions.

Answer (score 0):

When did this issue start to appear, was it after a configuration change to this VM? If not because of a configuration change, below steps should help:

Please ssh into the instance and run below command to see which Cloud SDK version and gsutil version you’re using: 'gcloud version'

As it appears to be a gsutil issue it might help to update your gsutil:

1. 'sudo gcloud components update gsutil'
2. Enter ‘N’ at the ‘Do you want to run install instead (y/N)?’ prompt and you should be able to update gsutil. You might have to use ‘sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk’ which should give you the same results, if Cloud SDK component manager is not enabled.
3. Check to see if above steps help.

Comment: Updating libraries didn't help. This is what I get from the gcloud version command:   Google Cloud SDK 189.0.0
alpha 2018.02.12
app-engine-java 1.9.60
app-engine-python 1.9.65
beta 2018.02.12
bq 2.0.29
core 2018.02.12
gsutil 4.28